# Checking for a variable of a Key of HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

My problem is I have a HashMap where the key is an object and I need it to be one of the variables in said object. Currently, the HashMap.get() only looks at the myNums Objects but I need a way to get the value of num1 as thats the "real key". I can't use the myNums.get() methods because I don't have an instantiation of myNums. I coud loop through each item in the HashMap to check but I'd prefer not to do that. Is there a more elegant solution?

What I have:

```
public static void main(String [] args){
   int [] array = {//integers 1-100};
   HashMap < myNums, String > hash = //data from another source;
   for(int i = 0;i < array.length; i++){
       if(hash.get(i) != null)
          OtherFunction(hash.get(i));         
   }
}

public class myNums{
   private int num1;
   private int num2;
   //get and set functions...
}
```

Comment: Why are you defining this HashMap using the Object if the real key is an int?  Why not HashMap<Integer, String>?  Or better, Use an ArrayList - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: For all intents and purposes, lets say I agree with you, but the decision is out of my hands

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan In the case that the key is not confined to a small range, it might be better to use a `Map` over a `RandomAccess` `List`.

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan It seems that he might be creating a multi-key map, where there are multiple int keys for each String value.

Comment: @veer Multimaps are multiple values associated with each key, not multiple keys for each value.

Comment: @Vulcan misread! To be fair, it seems like he wants to associate multiple values to each `myNums` (one for both `num1`, `num2`), so that seems like a multimap to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe an entry iteration serves more your purpose:

```
for (Entry<MyNums, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key:" + entry.getKey());
    System.out.println("Value:" + entry.getValue());
}
```

With this iteration style you don't have to invoke `get` all the time.

Comment: wont I still have to loop through the entire Set to check if its there? In this case it would be a small set so its not really an issue, but hypothetically if it were huge...

Comment: @Daniel Yes, that won't help then, but it's still better then iterating the whole collection and calling `get` in each step.

Answer (score 0):

You should override the hashCode() method and extend the equals() method of your class.

```
private class myNums{
  public int hashCode(){
    //Return something unique
  }
  public boolean equals(myNums that){
    return this.num1==that.num1;
  }
}
```

Comment: You can not overridden equals but overloaded it.

Comment: Thank you, @platzhirsch.  Overloading is when you have two methods with different parameters but the same name.

Comment: Correct. In your case you really want to implement `equals(Object obj)` and not `equals(myNums obj)`.

Comment: Oh, shit, you're right!  But really, you only need to implement myNums in this situation.  You can let the Object class return null for you.